# how to store screen output to a variable (linux)

Tags: bash, variables, capture

Using Ubuntu. I have a program which outputs its version when you use the -i parameter. The program itself will not do any further action, it just shows the version number and than exits.

Question is how to capture the output (so the version information) in a variable. I want to use it in a bourne shell later.

Assume the program is called "ABC". When I execute the command: ABC -i
than it shows: version 1.00 at the terminal screen. However when I enter in a terminal NR=`ABC -i`; echo ${NR} then there is nothing stored in NR.

```
root@shuttle:~# ABC -i
version 1.00
root@shuttle:~# NR=`ABC -i`
version 1.00
root@shuttle:~# echo ${NR}

root@shuttle:~#
```

I also tried this:

```
root@shuttle:~# NR=$(ABC -i)
version 1.00
root@shuttle:~# echo $NR

root@shuttle:~#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your program emits the version info on stderr rather than stdout ?

Comment: Thanks Paul.But since the info is visible in a terminal window is there a way to capture it to a variable?

Comment: @ni_hao You should post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
NR=$(ABC -i 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Thanks to Paul coz he puts me in the right direction (stderr)